# Copy and chmod/chown at the same time

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file owned by `root` that I want to copy into a directory owned by another user for him to analyse it (it must be uncompressed first).

Currently I'd have to

```
# cp log.xz /home/user/Documents
# chown user:user /home/user/Documents/log.xz
```

Is there a way to issue both commands at the same time, perhaps with one or more `cp` options?

Comment: you are asking about running multiple commands at the same time ?

Comment: @Vignesh I'm just asking how to do it the shortest way, perhaps with proper use of pipes ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cp man page does not list any options that would allow you to do this just with the CP command.  If you are wanting to just issue a command and "walk away", you can put the 2 commands on 1 line separated by a ;  to automatically execute the commands in sequence.

```
cp log.xz /home/user/Documents ; chown user:user /home/user/Documents/log.xz
```

Comment: Though trivial, I asked my question to see if there was any smart one-liner e.g. with proper use of pipes. It probably doesn't exist

Comment: I don't think its a good solution, but if you are dead set on using pipes, I came up with the following concoction which I suspect will work -  "cp -v /from.dir /to/dir 2>/dev/null | cut -f1 -d"'" | cut -c2- | xargs chown user:user "

Comment: Do scroll beyond the accepted answer if you really need an answer, folks...

Answer (score 48):

You might want to look at [`install`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install):

```
install -g user -o user log.xz /home/user/Documents
```

`install` has other options suitable for installing. e.g. set mode or preserve directory structure.

Comment: Nice tip. I tended to think "install" is meant to install things, but its actual summary in the manpage is: "install - copy files and set attributes"

Comment: @esperanto: The primary use of `install` is still to install files to the system. Some programs actually override `install` by modifying the PATH environment variable, so that files are installed elsewhere. Some package builders do that so files are not installed to the current system, but rather saved into a package.

Comment: It's `-g group -o user`. `-o` stands for owner.

Answer (score 1):

see map page of cp command

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve  the  specified   attributes   (default:
              mode,ownership,timestamps),   if  possible  addi-
              tional attributes: context, links, xattr, all

Answer (score 0):

From cp man page `-p` option should preserve the attributes including ownership:

```
-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```